# Definition of entropy and entropy flux of conservation laws: component-wise reasoning

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, entropy, conservation-laws

Consider the conservation law
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\dvg}{\operatorname{div}}
 \partial_t u(x,t) + \dvg G(u(x,t)) =0, \\
u \in U\subseteq \mathbb R^m, x\in X\subseteq \mathbb R^n, G \subseteq \mathbb M^{n\times m}(\mathbb R).
$$

We usually equip the system with an **entropy** (which is a scalar) $\eta$ with associate flux $Q \in \mathbb R^n$ related by
$$
DQ_{\alpha} =D\eta \cdot DG_\alpha, \quad\alpha = 1,2,\ldots, n. \label{1}\tag{$\ast$}
$$

Here are my concerns about this definition. In thermodynamics, the entropy flow is simply heat flux divided by temperature. **It is NOT defined by the equation stated above via some other quantity $u.$**

Therefore, I am puzzled by the following questions:

1. Is the thermodynamic entropy/entropy flux an entropy in the sense of the definition above? In other words, does the tranditional physical entropy arise from some quantity $u$ via the above equation? If so, what is the physical meaning of $u?$
2. Are there other nonequivalent definitions of "mathematical" entropy? After all \eqref{1} is not necessary for $\eta(u)$ to be conserved for smooth solutions. To make sure $\eta(u)$ is conserved for smooth solutions, we only need $\text{div }Q = D\eta \cdot \dvg G(U)$ which is of course a much weaker condition. **That leaves the possibility of defining other mathematical objects that looks somewhat like entropy.**

Answer (score 4):

Carlo's answer brings partial information. Let me complete it.

First of all, a general gas is not polytropic, thus the pressure is not proportional to $e-\frac12\rho u^2=:\rho\varepsilon$. In other words, there is not such beast as $\gamma$, or it is not constant. Thus the entropy $\eta$ is not given by a log-algebraic formula in terms of $p$ and $\rho$. Instead, it is a function $\eta=-\rho s(\rho,p)$, where $s$ is obtained from the (Gibbs) differential equation
$$\vartheta ds=d\varepsilon+pd\left(\frac1\rho\right)\,.$$

Even the above is not satisfactory, because the temperature $\vartheta$ is an integrating factor, which is far from unique. Actually, any $\bar s=h\circ s$ is another solution of the same equation, with $\bar\vartheta=\frac\vartheta{h'\circ s}$. Thus $\bar\eta=-\rho h\circ s$ is another entropy of the Euler system. This shows that the mathematical notion of entropy is far too wide.

Which one is the correct entropy ? To answer this question, one cannot stay at the level of the Euler equation, but we must take in account a diffusive effect, namely the Fourier law of heat diffusion. This leads us to working with either Euler-Fourier system, or even with Navier-Stokes Fourier. Anyway, the conservation of energy is written as a second-order PDE. The heat diffusion occurs through the right-hand side
$${\rm div}(\kappa\nabla\vartheta).$$
Now, the equations tell us what is the physical temperature, and thus what is the physical entropy. It is a theorem that ${\rm div}(\kappa\nabla\vartheta)$ cannot be recast as ${\rm div}(\bar\kappa\nabla\bar\vartheta)$, unless $h$ is an affine function. Thus every other entropy, admissible from the perspective of Physics, is a linear combination of $\eta$ and $\rho$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the mathematical entropy is more general than the physical entropy, but in many contexts of physical relevance these turn out to be the same quantities.

In particular, for the one-dimensional Euler equation the conserved quantities $U$ are the mass density $\rho$, momentum density $\rho u$ (with velocity $u$), and the energy density $e$. The corresponding fluxes $G$ are, respectively, $\rho u$, $\rho u^2+p$, and $(e+p)u$, with $p$ the pressure, producing the conservation laws
$$\partial U/\partial t +\partial G/\partial x=0.$$
The entropy $\eta$ with flux $Q=u\eta$ is then given by
$$\eta=\rho\log(p/\rho^\gamma),$$
where the exponent $\gamma$ appears in the equation of state
$$p=(\gamma-1)\big(e-\tfrac{1}{2}\rho u^2\big).$$
That this physical entropy satisfies the condition \eqref{1} in the OP required for a mathematical entropy, is checked for example in these [notes](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19900008060/downloads/19900008060.pdf) (page 12).

Comment: In one dimension the physical entropy must be a mathematical entropy - otherwise the entropy does not satisfy a conservation law. But in higher dimension, things are different - see my second point above. Do you have a three-dimensional example for the same thing?